# Resize UICollectionView cells after image inside has been downloaded

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm building a `UICollectionView` and my custom cells will contain two labels and one image.

Each image is downloaded asynchronously so I don't know it's size until the download it's complete. 
Once is downloaded, I want to adapt each cell to re-layout it's content and frame to fit in height the image just downloaded.

As `UICollectionViewLayout`, I'm using [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout)

To download the image asynchronously I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), like this:

```
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) 
                                {... some completion code here ...}];
```

QUESTION:

What is the right approach to resize each `UICollectionViewCell` right after the image is downloaded?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should just be able to invalidate your collection view layout in an animation block when the image comes back. Things might get a little complicated if more than one image finishes completion at once, but this should work:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)^{
                          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                              [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
                          }];
                      }];
```

Then just return a different size in the appropriate delegate method.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return /* a different size if the image is done downloading yet */;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a perfect result the first time the UICollectionView is loaded, but when it's loaded for the second time (i.e. moving to another view and coming back) I get weird cell frame sizes (smaller than expected, with content overlapping).
If I scroll a bit, everything is displayed properly again.
Do I have to change the cell frame size (and where) after the image is downloaded?

Comment: Solved. Actually there was nothing do nothing with the cell frame. I just had to set the cell.imageView frame just before the animateWithDuration block.  


`[cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(2,2,image.size.width,image.size.height])];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}];`

Comment: Should I be calling it this way with a callback because if I do I have an issue since it expects a return expression, since I have it called on each cell? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316634/how-to-cache-image-and-scale-it-correctly That is how I wrote it, and was actually trying the resize but it does not keep the aspect ratio and instead cuts out a piece of the image?

Comment: What did you return in size sizeForItemAtIndexPath method?

Answer (score 1):

To resize collection view cells, you could reload the collection view and return the size of you collection view cells dynamically in the method:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [cell size];
}
```

In cases when the cell's size is dynamic, get the cell from the index path and return its size based on the size of the image. I usually create a method for the cell to return a dynamic size, like in the example above. You can use UIImage's size property to help return the size based on the image.

Comment: When should I reload the collection view, after all the images are downloaded?

Or it's better to reload each cell with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths?

Comment: Doing it in this way you would have to reload the collection view after downloading all of the images.

Comment: +1 because even if your answer didn't solve my issue, I used the idea of a [cell size] method.
However @Ash solution was what I was looking for.

Comment: You should not call dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier: multiple times without returning the cell to the collection, e.g. in cellForItemAtIndexPath:. The collection will have hundreds of dequeued cells sitting around that are never returned to be reused.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for pointing that out! I updated the answer to use `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` for the cells that finished loading.