# how to resize dowloaded Image with SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to download images async into UICollectionView cells, but the downloaded images didn't fit the cell, where the cell only shows the upper corner of the image.

this is my code :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell

    cell.imageView.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
    cell.imageView.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageURL[indexPath.row]))

    return cell
}
```

and this's my cellClass :

```
private class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setupViews()
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .white
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return imageView
}()

func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = .white
    addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width , height: frame.width )

}
}
```

I had followed this link [Resize UICollectionView cells after image inside has been downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121663/resize-uicollectionview-cells-after-image-inside-has-been-downloaded) to solve it, but nothing changes.

So any ideas ?

Comment: hi @Mohammad did accepted answer worked for you?

Comment: @nikdange_me absolutely worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use auto constraints you should remove this line

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

You should use this when you use auto constraints programmatically

Comment: jazak allah kheer, (Thanks bro), could you please, explain more.

Comment: Take a look at these links [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/), [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) I think enough to catch the point

Comment: I appreciate it.